# JavaFx ListView EventHandler when pressing enter?

Tags: listview, event-handling, javafx

Is there a way to add an eventhandler to a ListView on pressing enter, like `setOnAction` for a TextField?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an setOnKeyPressed() and filter for the "return" key